# Detecting USB drives and placing drive letters into variables in a Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file that copies files from all the removable drives inserted that match a certain disk label. In this case "VIDEO"...

Existing code simply displays the detected drives and asks user to input themselves the drive letters.

It should never be more than 4 drives but should display an error if there are more than 4 detected.

QUESTION: How can I automatically set disk1, disk2, disk3, disk4 instead of forcing the user to do this?

EXISTING CODE:

```
echo Here are the drive letters of VIDEO cards  inserted:
for /f %%D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "VIDEO"') do echo/|set /p ="%%D   "
set "drive1="
if "%drive1%"=="" if %Cards% geq 1 set /p drive1= What is the FIRST video drive letter (example: d:): 
set "drive2="
if "%drive2%"=="" if %Cards% geq 2 set /p drive2= What is the SECOND video drive letter (example: d:): 
...etc..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nearly there. Just set your variable instead of the `echo/|set /p` construct and implement a counter:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f %%D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find /i "Video"') do ( 
  set /a count+=1
  set drive!count!=%%D
)
echo %count% drives found:
set drive 2>nul
if %count% gtr 4 echo too much...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a batch file that does kind of the same thing. Here's a part of the code :

```
@echo off
set yes=true
>nul find "%yes%" F:\hold.txt && (
  echo F:/ exists
) || (
  echo F:/ does not exist
)
pause
```

So in the drive that is inserted into F:/ I have a text file that is called "hold.txt" and in the file I just have 'true' typed in the text file. If you understand batch and the `FIND` command, you'll see why this works. It finds the file, and the text string, and tells the program to print "F:\ exists" in the fourth line of code above. Hope this helps!